# Como usar una imagen de boton html

Tags: html, css

Hola a todos, les quiero pedir ayuda ya que quiero usar una imagen de boton (para un checkbox), me refiero usar un boton que para hecer un menu adaptable a dispositivos moviles pero cuando la imagen esta sobre el boton y le doy click a la imagen no pasa nada, aqui esta el codigo.

```css
.menu_Menu{
    display: none;
}

header label img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

header label{
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

header label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}


#menu ul li a{
    margin: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    transition: all .5s;
}


#menu ul li{
    float: right;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#Inicio{
    float: left;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #222222, 1px 1px 0px #222222, 2px 2px 0px #222222;
}

header label{
    display: block;
}

.menu_Menu{
    display: block;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: -70%;
}

#menu ul li{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}

#Inicio{
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    font-size: 30px;
}

.menu_Menu:checked ~ #menu{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <input name="menuResponsive" type="checkbox" class="menu_Menu">
    <label for="menuResponsive"><img src="aqui va cualquier imagen" alt="Menu"></label>
    </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <a id="Inicio" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="Pag1" href="">Pagina 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="Pag2" href="">Pagina 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="Pag3" href="">Pagina 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Algo asi es mi codigo solo que en donde puse "cualquier imagen" va la imagen que sea, y perdon si mi css no es muy bueno esque apenas lo estoy aprendiendo, o tambien no se si la manera en la que lo estoy haciendo es la correcta, si estoy mal me ayudaria que me corrigieran. Les agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Usar JavaScript

Puedes usar Javascript, para añadir un evento a la imagen, al darle click se activa o desactive el checkbox

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".cont").forEach(el => {
  const img = el.querySelector("img");
  const box = el.querySelector("input");
  img.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (box.checked) {
      box.checked = true;
    } else {
      box.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cont {
  position:relative;
}

.cont > img {
  position:absolute;
  background:#f6f6f6;
  padding:13px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.cont > input {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <img src="" alt="Menu">
</div>
```

Usamos un contenedor `.cont` que almacenará la imagen y el input, al darle click, el contendor `.cont` debe tener una posición relativa, para que podamos usar posiciones absolutas en los elementos dentro de este, tanto el `<input>` como la imagen tienen una posición absoluta, le añadimos un evento a la imagen, cuando se haga click en esta, se activará el input si está desactivado y viceversa

---

#### 2. Usar CSS

Si prefieres hacerlo con CSS, puedes crear campos con un checkbox personalizado, para que podamos ocultar los estilos originales, tenemos dos contenedores, uno que es el que tendrá la posición relativa y el otro es un `<label>` que contendrá el `<input>`, el `<label>` tendrá una posición absoluta, asimismo la imagen

```css
.mainCont {
  position:relative;
}

.mainCont > img {
  padding:12px;
  background:#f6f6f6;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.cont > input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCont">
  <label class="cont"> &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="mainInp">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <img src="" alt="Menu">
</div>
```

---

```js
document.querySelector("#openImg").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (openBox.checked) {
    openBox.checked = false;
  } else {
    openBox.checked = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.menu_Menu{
    display: none;
}

header label img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

header label{
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

header label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}


#menu ul li a{
    margin: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    transition: all .5s;
}


#menu ul li{
    float: right;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#Inicio{
    float: left;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #222222, 1px 1px 0px #222222, 2px 2px 0px #222222;
}

header label{
    display: block;
}

.menu_Menu{
    display: block;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: -70%;
}

#menu ul li{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}

#Inicio{
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    font-size: 30px;
}

.menu_Menu:checked ~ #menu{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <input name="menuResponsive" id="openBox" type="checkbox" class="menu_Menu">
    <label for="menuResponsive"><img src="aqui va cualquier imagen" alt="Menu" id="openImg"></label>
        <nav id="menu">
            <a id="Inicio" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="Pag1" href="">Pagina 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="Pag2" href="">Pagina 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="Pag3" href="">Pagina 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Ya intente hacerlo tanto con javascript como con css y no funciona, cuando le doy click a la imagen no pasa nada :(, hay otra solucion

Comment: @Davidflogar ¿Podrías añadir el código donde no funciona?

Comment: Esque tambien lo intente hacer con tu codigo y no funciono, unicamente con tu codigo y no funciona, y despues cuando lo intento adapar a  mi menu tampoco, cuando le doy click a la imagen no pasa nada, no llega hasta el checkbox

Comment: @Davidflogar Comprueba la solución que puse en la edición

Comment: Okey, lo voy a intentar

Comment: Gracias, ya funciono :)